# Ethernet port not working on Raspberry Pi with GPIO pins connected

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, gpio, ethernet

Raspberry Pi model: 3B
Running Raspbian OS

Recently I bought a Hyperpixel 2.1 round, which uses all of the GPIO ports. Whenever I plug the Raspberry Pi into my network switch, it is unable to connect to the network with the Hyperpixel attached. However, when I removed the Hyperpixel, the Ethernet capability came back.
I'm fairly sure it's a software issue given that there shouldn't be any problems with running all gpio pins in addition to Ethernet.
Is this a quirk with the Raspberry Pi that it doesn't like having all GPIO ports occupied as well as Ethernet? And how would I potentially go about fixing this, perhaps through command line or in the boot config?

Comment: It might be power issue or some pins that are used as a muxes.